# What exactly is lime, lime-tools, aether, etc

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxelib

I understand the overall concept of the Haxe programming language and OpenFL, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the purpose of these various libraries and how they relate to each other and which ones are deprecated.

I've read that `lime-tools` is deprecated and became `aether`. I've read that `aether` is deprecated and became `lime-tools`. And I've read that both are deprecated and became `lime`. Upon writing this I've now also read that `aether` has been reintroduced.

I also don't understand the difference between `lime` and `openfl` itself as the commands seem to be identical; do they have different processes in accomplishing the same thing?

This has been an issue I've returned to a number of times in my attempt to get up to speed on the current state of Haxe development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lime-tools` and `aether` are both deprecated as of the 2.0.5 version of `lime`.

Originally `lime-tools` was called `haxe-tools` because the project format could be used for any development in Haxe. The Haxe Foundation suggested that it be changed because it wasn't an "officially" supported tool and thus `lime-tools` was created. It was kept separate from `lime` in hopes that it could still be used by someone not using `lime` or `openfl`.

During the development of `lime` 2.0 there was still discussion on whether to keep the tools separate or integrate them directly into `lime`. The decision was made to keep the tools generic enough for any Haxe development so `lime-tools` was renamed `aether` in the idea that the new name would be considered separate from `lime`. For a few releases `aether` was required to test/build `lime` and `openfl` projects until Joshua Granick (the primary maintainer of `openfl` and `lime`) decided to merge the tools with `lime` to simplify the installation process.

So as it currently stands `lime` contains all of the code from `lime-tools` and `aether`. You should use `lime <command> <target>` from a terminal to build/test/etc a project. `lime` also contains code to create an OpenGL context, handle input, and play audio. `openfl` is simply the layer on top of `lime` that acts as a replacement API for Flash and is now completely written in Haxe.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.robertshady.com/content/getting-started-cross-platform-game-programming-using-haxe-lime-and-openfl-part-1-installati

https://medium.com/kodemint-technologies/haxe-lime-openfl-ec9c2784aaa8

> Lime or Light Media Engine is the glue which helps make our Haxe code
>   to run in various native platforms. Lime exposes native functionality
>   like OpenGL, Audio, Input, Windowing etc (From the lime project readme
>   https://github.com/openfl/lime). Lime is the layer closest to our
>   targeted native platforms.
>
> OpenFl is an open source implementation of the familiar Flash API.
>   (The DisplayList based API that flash exposes. If you have experience
>   with targeting Adobe AIR all this will be very familiar). OpenFL
>   resides on top of Lime thus providing a true native experience.

Comment: Thank you for these links. However, I'm looking specifically for information on the relation between and state of development/deprecation of these various tools (`lime-tools`, `aether`, `lime`, `openfl`).

Comment: About Aether http://www.openfl.org/blog/2014/07/29/summer-update/

http://www.openfl.org/blog/2014/10/04/openfl-2-1-beta/ 
'Combined "aether"/"lime-tools" into "lime"'